# UFT runtime environment

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Do we have a way to  get uft runtime environment to run uft scripts ? Same like  java runtime for running java  applications and .net framework to run .net applications.

Comment: What do you want to do? Running the UFT test from other applications?

Comment: Actually, i want to integrate the UFT script in CHEF and run the automation test.
Apology for late response.

Answer (score 1):

You now can with the UFT Runtime Engine. More information can be found at this link.

From that site:

The UFTRuntime Engine enables you to run UFT tests (both GUI and API) and business process tests on your computer without installing the entire UFT IDE. In addition, you can also install the Runtime Engine without the Run Results Viewer, UFT Add-in for ALM, sample applications, or Help documentation. This can potentially save you valuable disk space on your computer

Answer (score 0):

Uft has a **Runtime Environment** Only installation (and a corresponding cheaper license as well - this has all the features except the *Development IDE*)

After you have installed it, you can either write your own little script to launch UFT Tests automatically using the Quicktest.Automation COM Object or use the **mdrv.exe** command line utility

https://learn2automate.blog/2016/07/05/how-to-execute-uft-test-silently/

Answer (score 0):

We can not achieve this with UFT 14 below versions we need version greater than 14.X.